# quarkus dev with sentry throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory

Tags: quarkus, sentry

While i am building a rest application with quarkus, i wanted to add sentry logging to get a clear feedback about errors in my project. So i added the following to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-logging-sentry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I am already using quarkus-resteasy-jackson but the following error occured while i was running the quarkus:dev maven plugin.

```
ERROR: Failed to start application (with profile dev)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.sentry.marshaller.json.JsonMarshaller.<init>(JsonMarshaller.java:124)
    at io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory.createJsonMarshaller(DefaultSentryClientFactory.java:526)
    at io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory.createMarshaller(DefaultSentryClientFactory.java:494)
    at io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory.createHttpConnection(DefaultSentryClientFactory.java:456)
    at io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory.createConnection(DefaultSentryClientFactory.java:356)
    at io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory.createSentryClient(DefaultSentryClientFactory.java:265)
    at io.sentry.SentryClientFactory.createClient(SentryClientFactory.java:178)
    at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.logging.sentry.SentryHandlerValueFactory.create(SentryHandlerValueFactory.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.SentryProcessor$addSentryLogHandler-1613402751.deploy_0(SentryProcessor$addSentryLogHandler-1613402751.zig:80)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.SentryProcessor$addSentryLogHandler-1613402751.deploy(SentryProcessor$addSentryLogHandler-1613402751.zig:40)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:608)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:38)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$3.run(StartupActionImpl.java:134)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

nov. 26, 2020 10:32:16 P.M. io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain firstStart
INFO: Attempting to start hot replacement endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
Quarkus application exited with code 1
Press Enter to restart or Ctrl + C to quit
```

I tried adding the jackson-core dependency to pom.xml as well but the error still occured. Then i tried building the project and start the jar in prod mode and suddenly it runs without any error. Sentry errors are being logged as well. Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: unfortunately, i did not. Its still occuring.

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in Quarkus 1.10. I downgraded to 1.9 and the error went away.

Comment: Should be fixed in 1.11.0.Final and later. See Quarkus Github issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14057